# Aborting a thread via its name

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-abort

I was wondering if it's possible to Abort (the dirty way) a thread using the threads name? here's some example code:

```
public void blah() {
   int TableID = 4; //set by the using at runtime

   Thread myThread = new Thread(() => beginUser(picture));
   myThread.Name = Convert.ToString(TableID);
   myThread.Start();
}
```

So now I have created a thread. Later in the program the user may end a thread, there is where my question comes in. How can I end a thread via it's name? or perhaps another way to end it? I don't want to use backround worker.

example: `myThead[4].Abort();`

thanks

Comment: What is the life time of this thread ? Are you mapping ths thread in dictionary <string,Thread> of <Thread.Name,Thread> ? Are all names going to be unique ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to keep track by dictionary (e.g. `Dictionary<string, Thread>`). Another way is to dig with `Process.Threads`. But in the first place why do you need that?

Comment: @Leri My program is for a bar to manage the usage of their pool tables. They Have big tables and small tables, my program allows them to dynamically add new tables to the forms panel, this will start a new thread and in this thread the program will do calculations (how long that table has been used, how much it will cost when they've finished using it) when the customer has finished using it the bar staff can right click the form, go to remove and remove the image of the table (s)he created, this requires me to end a thread. I could somehow send you the entire program if you like.

Comment: @user2864613 No, thanks, I've got my own projects. :D

Comment: I think you missed out the use of threads ! threads lifetime should be managed by the OS / Threadpool, work with thread pool - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply use a dictionary to store threadname to thread mapping and just kill from wherever you want.

```
Dictionary<string, Thread> threadDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Thread>();
Thread myThread = new Thread(() => beginUser(picture));
myThread.Name = Convert.ToString(TableID);
myThread.Start();
threadDictionary.Add("threadOne", myThread);

threadDictionary["threadOne"].Abort();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean.
Do you want to abort the thread in another method later? In that case this should work:

```
Thread myThread;    
public void blah() {
   int TableID = 4; //set by the using at runtime

   myThread = new Thread(() => beginUser(picture));
   myThread.Name = Convert.ToString(TableID);
   myThread.Start();
}

public void blub() {
   myThread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach. If you need to do something with the thread later, then don't use anonymous threads or local variables.